# microservice not able to locate zipkin service using discovery-server

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, zipkin

I have mircroservice environment based on spring-boot, where i am using zipkin server and discovery-server(eureka) and config-server. Now i have a rest-microservice which sends logs to zipkin server and this microservice is required to resolve where is zipkin server using discovery-server.

following is zipkin configuration i have in my rest-microservice's application.properties(pulled from config-server).

```
spring.zipkin.baseUrl=http://MTD-ZIPKIN-SERVER/
spring.zipkin.locator.discovery.enabled=true
spring.zipkin.enabled=true
...
```

here MTD-ZIPKIN-SERVER is zipkin-server name in discovery-server.

discovery-server dashboard.
[image]
but it does not try to resolve zipkin from discovery-server, instead it tries to connect directly using spring.zipkin.baseUrl, and i get below exception.

> Dropped 1 spans due to ResourceAccessException(I/O error on POST request for "http://MTD-ZIPKIN-SERVER/api/v1/spans":
>   MTD-ZIPKIN-SERVER; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   MTD-ZIPKIN-SERVER)
>
> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   POST request for "http://MTD-ZIPKIN-SERVER/api/v1/spans":
>   MTD-ZIPKIN-SERVER; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   MTD-ZIPKIN-SERVER     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:628)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:590)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin.RestTemplateSender.post(RestTemplateSender.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin.RestTemplateSender.sendSpans(RestTemplateSender.java:46)
>     at
>   zipkin.reporter.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter.flush(AsyncReporter.java:245)
>     at
>   zipkin.reporter.AsyncReporter$Builder.lambda$build$0(AsyncReporter.java:166)
>     at zipkin.reporter.AsyncReporter$Builder$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: MTD-ZIPKIN-SERVER  at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

if i provide exact zipkin url in property spring.zipkin.baseUrl like below

```
spring.zipkin.baseUrl=http://localhost:5555/
```

then my rest-microservice is able to connect to zipkin-server.

My goal here is to read zipkin-server location from discovery-srever. What am i doing wrong? Do i need to add some zipkin enabling annotation on my spring-boot rest-microservice?

Comment: You have to use Edgware release train for this to work. Which version of sleuth do you use?

Comment: I am using spring-cloud-sleuth-core-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar

Answer (score 3):

This feature is available in edgware release train. That corresponds to version 1.3.x of sleuth

Comment: For newer versions of spring (2+) where Zipkin server is completely separate project, can we still use this feature?

Comment: If you extend the zipkin server with service discovery then sure your can